# Foreign key naming conventions, ModuleID vs ModuleId

Tags: foreign-keys, naming-conventions

When we use foreign keys in table Should we name them **ModuleID** or **ModuleId**?

Due to foreign keys naming conventions.

Comment: Depends on who you ask, this is opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is defined by you or, if you're collaborating with other developers/DBA professionals, the convention will be particular to your team.

In my case, I prefer to stay with pascal-cased identifiers (i.e. `ModuleId`).